# How do I disable auto formatting into lists?

Tags: tinymce

When typing in the editor and using characters like a dash (-), when the user clicks enter, a list is automatically created. I want to disable this. I’ve tried removing the lists plugin and bullist from the toolbar but it didn’t have an effect. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by the `text_patterns` setting in the TinyMCE configuration:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/content-behavior-options/#text_patterns

As stated in the documentation:

This option allows configuring the text patterns that get matched while typing in the editor. Text patterns can be used to apply formats, replace text, or execute commands. By default, basic markdown patterns are enabled so the user can type `# text` to produce a header or `**text**` to make text bold.

To disable text patterns getting replaced, set the option to `false`.

The documentation also lists the default set of patterns so you could tweak that as needed if you don't want to simply turn off all of the patterns.